# why <iframe> in html links to youtube not working

Tags: html, youtube

```html
<div class="bodyhead">
  <h2>Challenge #1 - Fraction</h2>
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c33go2I&t=23s"></iframe>
</div>
```

then the youtube video gave me this error message "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: z6zBQ2dNPXoAhtDy)
Learn More"

Comment: Hard to tell. It does not run in the SO sandbox anyway

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the address with another embedded URL and it worked perfectly fine for me:

```
<iframe width="885" height="498" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c8VHzEFVmLA" title="YouTube video player" 
frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted- 
media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Make sure you right-click on the video and copy the embedded address precisely.